# Class not found error, is namespace usage wrong?

Tags: php, namespaces, classnotfound

I got a folder structure similar to:

```
top
 - folder1
    - file1
 - folder2
    - file2
```

Now when I write `$var = new \Namesp\class2` in file1, it tells me that the Class `class2` was not found.

file1:

```
$var = new \Namesp\class2;
...
```

file2:

```
namespace Namesp;
class class2 { ... }
```

Comment: Namespace != autoloader. Are you using an autoloader and if so, how is it set up? Or are you including the files?

Comment: As jeroen said Namespace != Autoloader. If you want to use namespaces, you *can* use Composer Dependency Manager https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Doesn't PHP natively support namespaces?

Comment: Natively supporting namespaces doesn't mean automagically including files

Comment: @Mark Thank you, I really didn't think of that, as I am working without composer and autoload for the first time! Sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake: Due to me never working without an autoloader before, I simply forgot to include the needed files before accessing them.

After doing that, everything worked as expected.
Thank you @Mark Baker